# syslog port with multiple clients

Tags: syslog, rsyslog, syslog-ng, syslog4j

I am having a syslog server configured in my localhost(Linux OS) which uses UDP 514 port.

I have different hosts trying to access the same port but the server is allowing only one client to access the port at a time.

Is there any chance or a way to access the same port from different clients at the same time??

Comment: There really needs to be more information and code samples provided here. We need to see how you are configuring your clients (Syslog) and server (SyslogServer). What does your SyslogServerConfigIF look like? Are you using an EventHandler?